# How to see draw digraph from scripts in terminal?

Tags: c++, graph, terminal, draw

When I run program I get  the results as tree written in graph scripts. How can I see actual graph - drawing?

My terminal looks like this:

[image]

I would like to see it like this for example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to search for applications or libraries.

Here is a good library:  [AT&T Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)